# Домашние и декоративные животные

Tags: значение-слов

Доброе время суток!

В чем разница между домашними и декоративными животными?

В [Биологическом словаре яндекса](http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_biology/1691) с одной стороны сказано, что "Домашние животные используются как транспортные, охотничьи, служебные и декоративные". С другой стороны написано: "Близки к домашним животным... декоративные и певчие птицы"

Т.е. если домашний - то можешь быть декоративным, если декоративный, то еще не факт, что домашний.

Так в чем разница?

И когда про декоративное животное можно сказать, что оно является домашним? И вообще можно ли так сказать - декоративное животное (например, морская свинка) так же является домашним животным?

Comment: Она - цесарка, он - ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Декоративный и домашний - эти разные признаки, они не относятся к одному ряду. Животные и птицы делятся на диких и домашних, но не на домашних и декоративных.

Декоративный - это нарядный, красочный, живописный, при этом нельзя считать, что декоративные виды - это те, которые не приносят практической пользы. Так, ленивый кот  не может стать декоративным, если он изначально собою не хорош, а "декоративный" котяра вполне  может проявить себя в ловле мышей.

Обычно говорят о декоративности ДОМАШНИХ птиц и животных, так как декоративность - одно их качеств, из-за которых их разводят люди (к примеру, есть птицы певчие и декоративные). 
Но декоративными (нарядными, живописными, красивыми) могут быть и дикие птицы. Например, можно прочитать следующее: "Канарейки - очень распространенные декоративные птицы. Дикие птицы несколько мельче одомашненных форм".

Comment: Т.е. декоративный - значит созданный для красоты?

А домашний (если грубо) - это тот, кого человек кормит и кому предоставляет кров (см. [википедию](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5))

Таким образом морская свинка - и декоративная, и домашняя, просто свинка - просто домашняя. А если какая-либо порода свиней разводится не для мяса, то можно считать жту породу декоративной?

Comment: Просто трудно представить вот [это](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%8F) декоративным )

Comment: Есть такой термин - декоративные породы птиц и животных, у специалистов все они расписаны. Морские свинки, наверное, все декоративные, а вот про кроликов говорится особо: "декоративный кролик".

Comment: Т.е. имеем (на примере ястреба):

- если ястреб рожден и живет на воле - это дикое животное,

- если он был диким, но попал к человеку и со временем стал, например, играть с человеком, кормиться с руки, никуда далеко не отлетать - то он ручное животное,

- если из ручных ястребов со временем вывели особую охотничью породу - то это уже домашнее животное,

- если же вывели породу, не способную к охоте - то это уже декоративное животное


Я все правильно понял?

Comment: И можно ли, например, павлина отнести к декоративным животным?

Ведь павлин - "это нарядный, красочный, живописный"

UPD: "Есть такой термин - декоративные породы птиц и животных, у специалистов все они расписаны" - перед тем как задать вопрос - гуглил про декоративных животных. Выдавало либо ссылки на домашних животных, либо ссылки на породы декоративных животных.

Т.е. нигде не нашел четкого определения что такое декоративное животное, поэтому спрашиваю здесь )

Comment: Про ястреба, думаю, все правильно, кроме декоративности, - это нужно уточнять, выведены ли декоративные породы. По поводу павлинов: они своей красотой приносят практическую пользу - именно используются их красивые перья для украшения шляп, шлемов, также мясо павлинов идет в пищу. Есть указание на то, что некоторые виды павлина могут использоваться как декоративная птица в садах, в то же время этому мешает их неприятный голос. Так что специального декоративного вида у павлинов нет.

Answer (score 2):

> По биологическому словарю - домашнее может являться декоративным, но ребенку на приеме у психиатра было сказано, что декоративные животные домашними не являются.

Так Вы бы психиатра и пытали. ;)
По сути Вам все сказали еще в словаре. 
Но, психиатр, видимо исповедует подход, что домашние - это только "физически" полезные - кошки, там, коровы... Чебурашки. А Крокодилы - нет, они только декоративные. ))).

> Т.е. если домашний - то можешь быть декоративным, если декоративный, то еще не факт, что домашний.

Нет, это скорее всего не это имелось ввиду под "близки к домашним". А то, что птицы - не животные. Ну или "не совсем животные".

Comment: Декоративные  -  это  разновидность  домашних.  Приглядитесь,  действительно,  к  психиатру  -  может  он  недавний  выпускник.

Answer (score 1):

Как назвать животных с которыми фотографируются на улице?

Они уже не дикие, но и не домашние.
Хотя, в то же время, ручные и в какой-то мере декоративные.